# Mule 2.2.1-HF5 compatible with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I was wondering if anyone knows if **Mule 2.2.1-HF5** could be executed with **Java 8**.

I have all my code developed in Java 6 with Mule 2.2.1-HF5 and, in order to migrate to Java 8 I will need to know if Mule 2.2.1-HF5 would be compatible with no code changes (i.e. executed in JRE 8)

Comment: why not just test it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. You will have to migrate to 3.7.x for full Java 8 support. See this [post](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/biz/anypoint-studio/intro-dataweave/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. When I try to run a flow with Mule 3.4.0 CE and jdk1.8.0_31 in Anypoint Studio it fails with this error:

> InitialisationException: JDK Version 1.8.0_31 and/or Vendor Oracle
>   Corporation are not supported.